# connecting to different databases using .net datasets

Tags: c#, dataset

I have many Databases with same structure and I have designed a dataset that matches the database design. It is easy to connect to database using connectionStrings which asked at design time and defined in app.config. But the problem arises when trying to change the database at runtime. I can not find any non-reflection solution to handle it. Is there any other way to change connection string of a dataset dynamically at run time or at least create dataset with different connection string!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are filling `DataSet` using `TableAdapter` and you can easily modify `TableAdapter` connection string like this:

```
myTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

gzaxx answer will not work, simply because different DBMS work with different ADO.NET providers, which may or may not be compatible with each other. There's a lot of theory behind it and I won't type all of that in this textbox, but you need to understand that is the TableAdapters that is the main issue, and not the DataTable. Your business and UI layers normally only talk to DataTables which will mostly have the same structure for almost any DBMS given that you have correctly used corresponding data types when creating table columns. So, in theory, if Typed DataSets could provide a way to attach multiple Adapters per DataTable, you could add one adapter for each DBMS you support, while keeping the DataTable structure the same.

I myself had to deal with this issue in a somewhat large project and the only workable solution for me was to separate my Data Access into a separate project (a class lib) and then create one such DLL for each DBMS I was supporting. Hope that helps you get started with this.